# GitHub plugins safe to use in my website?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-gravity-forms, github

I have some question about GitHub files, I hope it is a proper place to ask.

I downloaded the gravity forms from https://github.com/wp-premium/gravityforms

You may know that the plugin itself is sold by min price 59$/year in its website https://www.gravityforms.com/pricing

I am surprised if it is not free in the original website, how it can be downloaded for free at GitHub?

Do you think I can use the version from GitHub without any stability and safety issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub repository changelog is updated until version 2.4.20.

The official Wordpress is currently updated to version 3.1.25.

So in answer to your question, you can see that the GitHub repository appears to be abandoned, and therefore it does pose security flaws and you won’t get updates.